# Creating a menu using vectors, strings and arrays while reading from 2 text files

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector, fstream

Alright, I been trying to do this for a couple of hours but I'm not getting anywhere. First of
all, I have 2 text files that I need to read from a different function which is simple enough. Then for one of the text files, mainly the college.txt, I have to add it to a vector of strings; for the other text file(states.txt), I have to add the states to parallel arrays of strings.

The problem(This is related to the college.txt file) I have is how do I compare the strings the user inputs to the strings inside the vector since I have to validate whether or not the colleges/universities that the user inputs are on the list(and of course repeat it until the user decides to quit but that's also simple enough to do with a while loop).

Note1: Before you ask, The else/if with empty statements are empty because I want to focus on this problem first and then I will continue on with the program.

Note2: The IDE that I'm using is CodeBlocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool DoesStringEqualVector(vector<string> total, string name)
 {
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < total.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (name == total[i])
          return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

void collegesUniversities(string)
{
ifstream campuses;
campuses.open("colleges.txt");

string schools;
vector<string> schoolVector;

if(!campuses)
    cerr << "Error opening file. ";
else
{
  while(campuses.good())
   {
     getline(campuses,schools, '\n');
     schoolVector.push_back(schools);
     cout << schools << endl;
   }
}
DoesStringEqualVector(schoolVector, schools);

campuses.close();

}

int main()
{
char response;
string comparison;
int choice;
string userInput;

cout << "\nWelcome to my college and university search program.\n";
cout << "\nPress any button to continue.\n ";
                      system("pause>nul");

do
{
 cout << "\nPress 1 to enter possible colleges and universities.";
 cout << "\nPress 2 to find out how many colleges and universities";
 cout << " appear in your state.\n";
 cout << "Press 3 to find the total amount of colleges and";
 cout << " universities in our list. ";
 cout << "\nPress 4 to quit. ";
 cin >> choice;

  if(choice == 1)
 {
   do
    {
      cout << "\nEnter the name of your college/university. ";
      cin >> userInput;

      collegesUniversities(comparison);

      if(userInput != comparison)
        cout << "\nThis institution isn't on out list.\n ";
      else
        cout << "\nThis institution is on the list.\n";

      cout << "\nWould you like to return to the menu?[Y/N] ";
      cin >> response;

      while(response != 'Y' && response != 'y' && response != 'N' &&
          response != 'n')
      {
          cerr << "\nError, Invalid Input.";
          cin >> response;
      }
    }
    while(response != 'N' && response != 'n');
   }

   else if(choice == 2)
   {

   }

  else if(choice == 3)
   {

   }

  else if(choice == 4)
   {
    cout << "\nThank you for using my program. ";
    cout << "Have a great day.\n ";
   }

  else
   {
    cerr << "\nError, Invalid input. ";
    cout << "Only integers from 1 through 4 are allowed.\n";
   }
  }
   while(choice != 4);
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a way to check whether a string is already in a vector?

Comment: I want to check whether if the string the user inputs(string userInput) matches to what's in the vector string. So if the user inputs Florida international University and this institution is on the list, it should display cout << "This institution is on the list.";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it all up in a method that checks through the vector:

```
bool IsStringInVector(vector <string> collection, string item)
{
    for (int i=0; i < collection.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (item == collection[i])
              return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You have to scan through the collection to see if it's in there.

Comment: Well first of all, I changed int with an unsigned int because my compiler said that there was a comparison between a signed and unsigned(the vector and the int). Then I placed this function inside my void function and replaced the arguments inside the bool function with the vector and string inside my void function. Then when I ran the program and typed a college/university that I know is in the list, It produces bugs like infinite loops and outputting "Error, invalid input" many times. To be honest, I'm lost at what I need to do. You have any pointers?

Comment: I don't know if you're still having these problems, but you shouldn't be loading from the file each time. Reading from files is a fairly expensive operation and assuming you have a large file, this is going take a long time. May as well just load it once at the beginning of the program, and pass it in to check each time.

Comment: Also your function `collegeUniversities` doesn't pass in anything, just an empty string variable. Honestly I'm surprised that's valid C++ syntax, seems like an oversight. Also you're passing in an empty variable anyway, `comparison` is never initialised.